# "__" is not accessed | Pylance | Binance API | VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, websocket, binance-api-client

I am fairly new to python and using VScode. I have been trying to work on a fairly simple project and I've been stuck at this problem for quite some time now.

I have created a venv in which I have assigned the correct venv interpreter path within VScode. All I am trying to do is use binance's websocket to retrieve live data at 1 minute intervals.

I have two problems, in which one may be causing the other. The "ws" as my input shows a warning that is not being accessed by Pylance. When I run my program on VScode, nothing happens... all I see in the terminal was that my code executed but I do not see any data being retrieved.

What's weird is that if I run the same code in Google Collaboration the code executes perfectly... this leads me to believe I have to have something wrong within my VScode settings. I have followed the [Binance Documentation](https://github.com/binance-us/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md) but still no luck. Please help, I've been stuck on this for days and cannot find the answer. Any help will be appreciated greatly!!

```
import websocket
socket = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m'

def on_open(ws):
  print('Connection Open')

def on_close(ws):
  print('Connection Closed')

def on_message(ws, message):
  print(message)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket,on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)

ws.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when the module is installed in another environment and it is not selected.
to solve it you have to change the execution environment as indicated in the images.
or else in vscode View => command Pallete =>python select interpreter
It worked for me, I hope it works for you

[image: this is the problem]

[image]

[image: solution]